# Using `tag.find_all` for an accessor with random numbers (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<a href="some_url" game_id="Some integers"</a>
```

"Some integers" are numbers that change in every href link.

From this I would like to extract the href "some url".

My code now:

```
for link in table.find_all("a",{"game_id":?}):
    href=link.get(href)
```

What I should put in "game_id": question mark so the code could detect the href links?

Comment: You should put `"Some integers"`, as simple as it gets. Also, you need to change `href=link.get(href)` to `href=link.get('href')`.

Comment: Is the href part of a `class` or some other data-oriented attribute?

Comment: @LukaszSalitra Yes there is also "season_id" which is always 93783, so "season_id"=93783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first bit, you'll need `regex` to handle this.

```
import re
for link in table.find_all('a', {'game_id' : re.compile('\d+')}):
    href = link.get("href") # or href = link["href"]
```

Furthermore, you may use double-quotes to access the `href` field.

Comment: you got into the same trap as I did when trying out OP's code, it's missing the `:`  :)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar My bad! Just noticed. Ty.

Comment: I just edited the original post. The "some integers" are numbers like "5267" that change in every href link. The problem is that I can't put any specific argument into game_id tag because the integers are changing in every href link.

Comment: @JuhoM Please refer to my comment in main post.

Comment: @JuhoM Edited. You'll need regex.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @JuhoM Glad to help. Next time, be a little more clear that you wanted actual numbers and not a string saying "Some numbers" :p Cheers.